# How do I stop my <httpErrors> 404 "ExecuteURL" mapping from breaking my form?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a custom 404 page, and I'm having a problem where the 404 mapping breaks a form on that page.

I've configured my site to execute and return my custom 404 page on every page not found:

```
 <httpErrors existingResponse="Auto">
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="17" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="17" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
 </httpErrors>
```

My master page includes a form wrapping all content:

```
<form runat="server">
```

If I go to /xyz (i.e. not a real page), the form action is given as pointing to that non-existing page:

```
<form method="post" action="xyz?404%3bhttp%3a%2f%2fsite.example.com%3a80%2fsite%2fxyz" id="ctl01">
```

So if I submit a postback (e.g. a button onclick) on that page, the postback is POST'ed to /xyz  – which, of course, isn't an actual page, so we get redirected to our 404 *before form processing takes place*. As a result, the onclick never gets called.

I'm *guessing* that I need to somehow force the form action to point at the actual page (/404.aspx) instead of the missing page (/xyz) – but how do I do that?

Comment: Why does your 404 page have a postback option?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: it's the "search" form in the header. I'd really like it to work, because I'm assuming that one of the first things users are going to do when they hit a 404 page is to search the site for what they were originally looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, your problem is with a site-search form on your master page.

I would recommend you move that site-search form *outside* of the form tag with `runat="server"`. Here is why:

1. The new form will then always submit to your search page (or I've done it where it executes a JavaScript function).
2. This will fix any issues you have with people pressing "enter" and it submitting the wrong form. This way, "enter" on the search form will submit the search form, and "enter" on a form inside the form tag with `runat="server"` will submit that form... and you don't have to mess around with default buttons or catching enter-button presses.

Side note: You can have multiple forms on a page, just not a form within a form, and you can't have two forms with `runat="server"` on them.

Comment: Thanks @MikeSmithDev, this was good advice. I've moved the search form out of the form runat server, and that's solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which I found that works is to just redirect the forum action to the correct URL. Quick and easy solution.

```
Form.Action = "/500.aspx"
```